# Intel® RST Mirror data

Tags: windows-10, raid, mirroring, intel-rst

Something broke my mirror RAID(1).
I ended up with two disks in windows that was not synced.

How do a create a new mirror raid from an HDD with data on it. I **dont** want a blank new mirror raid. I want one disk to mirror to the other drive.
Intel® RST in windows you have the option to chose the drive you want to keep data from when create an raid. The problem is that Intel® RST windows just crash when i try to do that.
Intel® RST in "bios-mode" there i can only create raid(1) that will erase the data on both disks. I dont want that i want one disk to be mirrored to the other.

Any ide on how mirror the disks in Intel® RST?

Comment: Consider clearing one of the drives then rebuilding the array by seeding it with the drive with data on it.

Comment: What do you mean by seeding?
One of the drive will be clean off course. 
Thats the one i want to mirror data too.